# How to get the vertices which have high betweenness in a network

Tags: r, graph, statistics, social-networking

I have a graph with 198 vertices and 2742 edges.I am using R

I would like to find the nodes which has high betweenness. But when I compute the below code, I get the betweenness score of all 198 nodes. I would like only the top 5 nodes with high betweenness, so I could remove them later to see how the network structure changes.

> >
>   betweenness(g)

g is a igraph

Comment: `sort(betweenness(g), decreasing = T)[1:5]` should do it.

Comment: This gives me the betweenness scores. But I am looking for the vertices names corresponding to the scores. I would like something like this(node1,node5,node20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector information is already contained in the betweenness calculation. The betweenness function generates a named object.

It would help if you provide your data - maybe you do not have names for vectors to begin with. The solution is then go back and assign names for the vectors, otherwise igraph will generate a simple sequential ID for you.

I created this toy sample for demonstration.

```
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David","David", "Esmeralda","Cecil","Tom"),
to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice","David","Cecil"))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE)

bc <- betweenness(g)
bc 

  #Bob     Cecil     David Esmeralda       Tom     Alice 
   # 0         3         0         0         0         0
```

If you can get a result like this, then turn the named list into df for easier manipulation, like sort or select.

```
bc.daf <- as.data.frame(bc)
```